# What is the correct way to initialize a Matrix in C++98?

Tags: c++, mingw, c++98

1. I'm not programmer
2. I want to compile Inkscape in win32, and stumbled on these error messages:

> ui/dialog/filedialogimpl-win32.cpp:1379: error: in C++98 'matrix' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'
>   make[1]: *** [ui/dialog/filedialogimpl-win32.o] Error 1

The suspected code of `filedialogimpl-win32.cpp`:

```
...
    // Draw the image
    if(_preview_bitmap_image)    // Is the image a pixbuf?
    {
        // Set the transformation
        const Matrix matrix = {
            scaleFactor, 0,
            0, scaleFactor,
            svgX, svgY };
        context->set_matrix (matrix);
...
```

So how is it written in C++98 standard?

I've googling it but no one encountered that way, could it be unrelated?

Comment: Are you sure you've used the right tools (compiler)?

Comment: Where did you get the code, and are you sure it hasn't been changed since the last known good configuration?  What compilers and such was it targetted for, and what are you using?  And why are you compiling when you aren't a programmer, rather than downloading the MS Windows .exe file?

Comment: Oh...there is nothing in the standard called Matrix.  That's a class defined in the source code somewhere.  Do text searches for "class Matrix" and "Matrix::Matrix" and post some of that code, if you want help.  Or post exactly where you got the source code, and what the exact filename is on the source code (typically a .zip file for MS Windows).

Comment: I use msys + mingw, its from http://202.55.147.10/sourceforge/i/project/in/inkscape/inkscape/0.47/inkscape-0.47.tar.bz2
I build most of dependencies myself, except for gtk/gtkmm and gc. 


@David thornley
The problem with current binaries is they are huge (unusually huge dlls). So I try build it myself and avoid using btool.
I can do some scripting, but certainly no C/C++ skill.
Surely you don't need .zip (its too huge)...Anyway Its cross platform. I do have 7zip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

`const Matrix matrix = {
            scaleFactor, 0,
            0, scaleFactor,
            svgX, svgY };`

there should be something like this:

`const Matrix matrix(
            scaleFactor, 0,
            0, scaleFactor,
            svgX, svgY );`